# What does "Log out" do precisely?

Tags: gnome, logout

The question is simple and mainly theoretical rather than a bug or an issue.

When I "log out" from Ubuntu<sup>[1]</sup>, what happens exactly? This doesn't seem to map with any Unix/Linux concept I'm aware of, so I'm guessing it's implemented at a higher level.

- Is this related to the desktop environment/shell?
- Is this related to the *Xorg* server?
- Does it simply shut down all non-system/user *systemd* services?
- Does it simply kill all processes owned by my Unix UID?

I couldn't find this information on [the Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/shell-exit.html.en).

<sub>[1]: Am I actually logging out from *Ubuntu*, or just from *GNOME*?</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long ago, when X ran as root, things were complicated. Less so now.

Key point: The login screen looks like it's part of the graphical desktop, but it's not. It's the display server, and it's job is to show you a pretty login screen, and then to start the rest of desktop enviornment.

The display server (Wayland since 2017 for most folks) no longer runs as root. It runs as your user.

Everything you do after login, including graphical applications and virtual terminals, runs as child processes of the display server.

When you logout, the display server resets, and all child processes are terminated. The login screen means you're back to the bare display server.

Comment: You perfectly answered my question. I had no idea that the login screen ran without X/Wayland. Last little clarification: when you mention "children" of the display server, do you mean child processes (in Unix terms) or just processes that are currently connected to the server (in some Wayland-specific terms)? In the first case, does this mean that disowning a GUI process started from a shell would make it stay alive after logout? (although it may choose to exit as soon as the connection to the display server is interrupted)

Comment: The login screen is _not_ part of Plymouth. At best Plymouth will show a prompt for a password to unlock an FDE disk, but the login screen proper is part of the display manager, such as GDM, LightDM, etc. It is a part of the graphical desktop, but the desktop of the user that the display manager is using (e.g., to configure the monitor settings for the GDM login screen, you need to use the `gdm` user).

Comment: @muru you're right, of course. Big edit to correct.